# Returning a blob from a Firebase function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to return a blob from a firebase function :

```
exports.urlToBlob = functions.https.onRequest((request,response) => {

      cors(request, response, () => {

        var url = "https://...";/ 
          fetch (
              url,
              {
                 method: 'GET',
                 headers: { 'Accept': '*/*' }
              }
           )
           .then ((res) => res.blob())
           .then ((blob) => {

              //return response.send(blob);
              console.log(blob);
              return response.end(Buffer.from(blob), 'binary');
           })
           .catch((err) => response.status(400).send(err))

       });
    });
```

This will **print me the blob bytes correctly**, but will also return 400 error.

```
RESPONSE RECEIVED FROM FUNCTION: 400, {
  "code": "ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE"
}
```

**Next**, i tried using this, which will return an empty object to the client, but will print it ok on the shell :

```
return response.send(blob);
```

How do you return a blob ?

Comment: anyone ? i am struggling with such a simple thing for a day :(

Comment: Why would you need blob instead of buffer?

Comment: thanks, does it matter ? i need any sort of file to return to a client (due to CORS)